# draw_line() in GDScript

Tags: godot, gdscript

I need help writing a piece of code that allows me to draw lines so that they are interspersed in my scene, similar to a triangle as shown below:

[image: Mr. Cool]

I created the algorithm like this:

**game.gd**

```
extends Node

const GRID_SIZE : Vector2 = Vector2(800, 480)
const CELL_SIZE : Vector2 = Vector2(32, 32)

const CELL_AMOUNT : Vector2 = Vector2(GRID_SIZE.x / CELL_SIZE.x, GRID_SIZE.y / CELL_SIZE.y)
```

**grid.gd**

```
func _draw() -> void:

# draw horizontal lines
for i in Game.CELL_AMOUNT.y:
    var from : Vector2 = Vector2(Game.GRID_SIZE.x / 2, i * Game.CELL_SIZE.y)
    var to : Vector2 = Vector2((i + 1) * Game.CELL_SIZE.x, from.y)
    draw_line(from, to, Colors.BLACK)
```

Can someone help me?
Is it possible to make these lines interact with the player? In the sense of, ''the player can step where the line is...''?

Comment: Are you trying to avoid additional `Node`s? If so, do you want to poll the positions or do you want a callback? It also unclear to me if you want physics at all. The things, yes, we can take control of everything and do it without using what Godot provides - I'll answer that version if that is what you want - or we can figure out what is the best way to use what Godot provides to archive the same goal, except I'm not sure what is the goal (e.g. Are this cells and the players moves between them discretely, or is it physics driven). I worry you are setting up for a harder task than needed.

Comment: Without a doubt, the way I'm doing it doesn't seem sensible to me. I think it will be much better to create the platform node and arrange them as I want, only changing colors when tapped. Now I just need to think about how to reproduce the player's physics, similar to the game I posted the image.

Comment: Reverse image search suggest that game is Mr. Cool. After watching game play footage of the game, I'm not convinced it used physics the way we would do them in a modern game engine. It seems closer to animate the character in a predefined parabola. So you have an state machine where you store if it is moving or static, and keep track of the position, and there would be collision code for the platforms.

Comment: Without a doubt, I'm in the development phase, learning to program. I want to reproduce this physics from the game and yes it is Mr. Cool. However, I'm a little lost.

Comment: I managed to improve the issue of blocks, in fact there are simpler ways to do it. Now I'm failing the mission to create the character, where he has to go down the blocks until I ask him to change the diagonal.